# How to get text of an element that keeps changing in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, element

I am just trying to automate a website like [Replika](https://replika.ai/) (the chatbot). In it, a new chat always keeps coming but with a whole new xpath and id. It's getting difficult for me to track the recent chat with selenium. I did try the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681857/scraping-text-from-an-element-that-the-xpath-keeps-changing-using-selenium-and-p) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745894/how-to-select-an-element-that-keeps-changing-with-selenium), but they didn't work for me (or maybe I did something wrong with it). I have just started to use selenium so I don't know a lot of things about it. Please help me out. I am using python 3.8.2.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://my.replika.ai/")
time.sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/main/a[2]""").click()

time.sleep(2)



### Login ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="emailOrPhone"]""").send_keys("gmail_id")
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/button""").click()
time.sleep(3)



### Password ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login- 
password"]""").send_keys("gmail_password")
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/button""").click()
time.sleep(10)


### Accept the cookies ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button""").click()
time.sleep(5)


### Getting the Latest text ###  Here is where it doesn't work
# This is a implementation that I tried and it didn't work
url = "https://my.replika.ai/"

# We use try-except in case the request was unsuccessful because of
# wrong URL
try:
    page = urlopen(url)

except Exception:
    print("Error opening the URL")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find('div', {"id": "chat-messages"})

chat = ''
for i in content.findAll('span'):
    chat = chat + ' ' + i.text

print(chat)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `so I don't know a lot of things about it.`  So does no one knows your code and what are your trials. Please take a look at [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post again.

Comment: Sorry  about the mistake, the post is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://my.replika.ai/")
time.sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/main/a[2]""").click()

time.sleep(2)


### Login ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="emailOrPhone"]""").send_keys("username")
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/button""").click()
time.sleep(5)


### Password ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-password"]""").send_keys("password")
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/button""").click()
time.sleep(3)


### Accept the cookies ###
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//* 
[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button""").click()
time.sleep(5)


a = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-author]")

print([i.text for i in a])


print("last text : " + a[-1].text)
```

just use the locator
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-author]")

this finds all the elements that has the attribute @data-author (only chat has this property) and access a[-1] to get the last element . call a[-1].text to get text from it

Comment: Oh thanks ! it worked! I got to know about browser.find_element(s). Thank you very much for looking into my problem.